# Microsoft BizTalk message format

Tags: .net, jms, biztalk, messaging, esb

I'm a bit confused about specifications used for messaging in MoM or ESB, whatever BizTalk is.
Are there any BizTalk message format that can be used when sending messages through it, or JMS message format specification is the common alternative that is used in BizTalk?

I have .NET apps from one side, and from other side of ESB and I have BizTalk in the middle. Do I have to wrap these messages in JMS format and send it through BizTalk or there is some kind of message format that is typical for BizTalk?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of how BizTalk will integrate with a JMS ESB - e.g. BizTalk has an ESB Toolkit, which has a [JMS ESB example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee250244%28v=bts.10%29.aspx).

However, the following may help in the general sense?

Internally, [BizTalk uses XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BizTalk_Server), and there is no requirement for incoming messages to have any specific enveloping, headers / footers etc - messages can be of any valid XML format.

e.g. if you are Integrating with Websphere MQ, BizTalk is only interested in the body component of the MQ message (which should be XML).

(If you have control over message schemas in your organisation, it certainly won't hurt to 'standardize' these messages into a common format, e.g. including standard header and footer sections for your own ease of identifying a message)

BizTalk identifies message 'types' primarily based on their Root Node name and its namespace (of the format `xmlns#root`), so ideally these should be unique for each message type.

BizTalk can also read data from other formats (e.g. flat text files, UN EDIFACT, etc)  although it will typically need to be able to parse it into XML in order to be able to do any content based routing, mapping to another format, etc

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say this, but it depends on your BizTalk installation.
BizTalk offers you an endpoint (Port in Biztalk terminology) which will accept whatever it was specified for. BizTalk may simply route your message to a (or several) destination systems, but doing so it may (but doesn´t have to) also apply transformations to the message before delivering it.

Wrapping it up, having BizTalk you shouldn´t have to worry about the destination system but only on what was negotiated to be passed to BizTalk.

What is the Port you´re talking to, a queue or a service?